# remove title bar or add button to it in sencha

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

This is screenshot of my sencha app deployed on android. I view two blue bars on the top. what i want is just to remove one of them. Any idea how to do it?

[image: Remove title bar or add button to it]

The codeis given below. hope this will help

```
Ext.define('appointMeDr.view.signUp.SignUp',{
extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype:'signUpXType',
config:{
    scrollable:'vertical',         
    items:[
         {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        title: 'Sign Up',
        docked: 'top',
       items:[ {
            xtype:'button',
            text: 'Back',
            ui:   'back',
            cls: 'back',
            name: 'backToLogin'
        } 
       ]
    },
    { 
        xtype:'fieldset',  
         defaults :{
            labelWidth : '120px'
        },
        items:[
        {
            xtype:'textfield',
           label:'<sup>*</sup> Full Name: ',
            placeHolder:'Full Name',
            name:'name'               
        },
        {
            xtype: 'emailfield',
            label: '<sup>*</sup> Email',
            placeHolder:'Email',
            name: 'email'
        },
        {
            xtype:'textfield',
            label:'<sup>*</sup> User Name: ',
            placeHolder:'User Name',
            name:'username'               
        },
        {
            xtype: 'passwordfield',
            label: '<sup>*</sup> Password',
            placeHolder:'Password',
            name: 'password'
        },
        {
            xtype:'textfield',
            label:'<sup>*</sup> Age: ',
            placeHolder:'Age',
            name:'age'               
        },
         {
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            name:'gender',
            label: 'Gender',
            options: [
            {
                text: 'Male',  
                value: 'Male'
            },
            {
                text: 'Female', 
                value: 'Female'
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype:'textfield',
            label:'<sup>*</sup> Address : ',
            placeHolder:'Address',
            name:'address'               
        },
        {
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            name:'Domain',
         label: 'Select Domain',
            options: [
            {
                text: 'Patient',  
                value: 'first'
            },

            {
                text: 'Doctor', 
                value: 'second'
            },

            {
                text: 'Guardian',  
                value: 'third'
            },
            {
                text: 'Attendant',  
                value: 'forth'
            }
            ]
        }

        ]
    },{
        xtype:'panel',
        margin:'10px',
        items:[
        {
            xtype:'button',
            text:'Sign Up',
            flex:1,
            name:'userSignUpBtn',
            docked:'right'
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

});

Comment: How can one help you without any clarification and related source code?

Comment: In which container do you have your sign up panel? If I add sign up panel directly to viewport, i see only one blue bar as you want: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/29h

Answer (score 5, accepted):

youre probably using a navigation view and loading another panel which contains a toolbar into the navigation view so what you get is 
1. blue bar from the navigation view 
2. 2nd blue bar from the panel view

What you could do is load the view directly into the viewport instead of the navigation view 
hope this helps :)